# How can I obtain a random number for each column in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, random

I have a matrix with n columns and 2 rows. But for each column I would like to pick a random number.
I have been searching about this but I´ve gotten nothing.
At this point I am using very small matrices but my code will be applied to big matrices.

I have this matrix, (more columns will be added)

```
          [,1]     [,2]
fcMax 2.391416 1.390129
fcMin 2.316555 1.374918
```

and I want to obtain a vector with dim = n (in this case 2, the number of columns), which is constructed by choosing a random number for each column.

Comment: I saw that your rows are named fcMax and fcMin. Does that mean that random numbers you want need to be generated from uniform distributions with different lower and upper bounds?

Comment: No, it´s not continuous. I just have to get one of those numbers, either fcMax or fcMin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop over the column with `apply` and then get use `sample`

```
 apply(m1, 2, sample, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
rand_row = sample(1:nrow(your_matrix), size = ncol(your_matrix), replace = TRUE)
result = your_matrix[cbind(rand_row, 1:ncol(your_matrix))]
```